# How to locate element from iframe tag in robot framework ride editor

Tags: iframe, robotframework

My website [link](http://dev.partistaff.com.au/), I want to sign up as FIND A JOB and fill up the form by robot framework automation. I also use following scripts on ride editor

```js
Open Browser ${url} ${browser}
Maximize Browser Window  
Click Link xpath://a[@class='mframe-sm btn-blue cboxElement']
Wait Until Page Contains Element xpath://a[@class='mframe-sm btn-blue cboxElement']
#Select Frame xpath:/body[1] ....> not working
#Click Element xpath://body   ....> not Working
Select Frame index=0 ....> Show an error message Element with locator 'index=0' not found.
Click Link     xpath://a[@href="/Register"]
```

On the sign up pop-up section, the element is not located. Also, driver is not able to click on the "Find A JOB link" from Sign up pop-up. Please take a look and could you please give a solution to locate the element on the iframe.

Comment: You don't show any error messages, and you don't explain why some of the statements are commented out.

Comment: @Bryan, Thank you for your feedback. I have updated it accordingly.I already tried 5-8 days, did not get a solution. Could you please give me a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath `//body[1]` is not the xpath of the frame. To select the frame, you need to give it the xpath to the frame element.

Example:

```
Select Frame  //iframe[@class='cboxIframe']
```

Comment: Thank you for your great reply. Error message "Element with locator 'xpath://iframe[@class='cboxIframe']' not found." is found after using your xpath.video link may be found on https://www.screencast.com/t/P9Ny0UiqElKn Could you please take a look and give a solution.

Comment: Did you check it. Please advise.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your example is working on Chrome browser( latest version), But, Error message "error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine" appears for Firefox browser(version:61.0.1) driver version (gecko driver-v0.21.0-win64) Could you please take look is it driver version problem for Firefox.